# Castle Windsor WCF client generation with differing addresses

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor

I'm using castle windsor wcf facility to create clients with the code below. I would like to be able to dynamically set "mypath" to something different for each client proxy thats created. I have a feeling this could be done with a typed factory and passing the string as a parameter, but im not able to get it done.

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMyService>().AsWcfClient(
    new DefaultClientModel
        {
            Endpoint = WcfEndpoint
            .BoundTo(new NetNamedPipeBinding() {}).At("mypath")
         }));
```

Comment: How do you propose to determine the address?

Comment: I would prefer to supply the address as a parameter in a factory function, but in the worst case a public static var.